# AngularJS x-editable typeahead with conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, typeahead, x-editable

trying to achieve the following behaviour with angular & x-editable:

I have an Add User form with 1 required input: "Name".
When adding a User there are 2 options:
1. If the User exists in the $scope.names I use typeahead to display the option list -> OK
2. If the User is new (not in $scope.names) then I should have a second required input "Email" and I should only display it when typeahead finds no match for my "Name" Input

And this is where I'm stuck... I don't really know how to apply the following "raw" condition:
**if user is not in users -> show Email Input**

Any help would be much appreciated!
Here is the
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wbf8C/12/)!

```
<div  ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="InvestorsController">   
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="investor in investors">  
                <span href="#" editable-text="investor.name" e-placeholder="Name" e-name="name" e-form="investorsForm" e-typeahead="name for name in names | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" e-required>
                    {{ investor.name || 'empty' }}
                </span>
                <form editable-form name="investorsForm" ng-show="investorsForm.$visible" class="form-buttons form-inline" shown="inserted == investor">
                    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="investorsForm.$waiting" class="btn btn-primary sx-btn-ok">OK</button>
                    <button type="button" ng-disabled="investorsForm.$waiting" ng-click="investorsForm.$cancel()" class="btn btn-default">X</button>
                </form>
                <div class="buttons" ng-show="!investorsForm.$visible">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="investorsForm.$show()">OK</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeInvestor($index)">X</button>
                </div>
            </li>
            <button class="" ng-click="addInvestor()">Add Investor</button>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As said previously, you could try to get the input value and check if exists in list, if the value isn't in the list the optional input will be shown.

```
$scope.shouldHide = function(index) {
    //get the typeahead input value:
    var nameInput = document.getElementsByName('name')[0]
    var nameValue = null
    if (nameInput){
      nameValue=document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value;
    }

    if (nameValue){
    //check if typeahead input value is in list
    $scope.names = ['User 1', 'User 2', 'User 3', 'User 4', 'User 5', 'User 6'];
       return $scope.names.indexOf(nameValue) >=0
    }   
    return true;
};
```

I fork your fiddle and added the explained behaviour here: http://jsfiddle.net/nachoorme/RZK9u/1/

Answer (score 1):

I would add something along the lines of: `ng-hide="shouldHide()"` in the span that is the email input.

Now, the shouldHide function should always grab the value from the name input and check it against the names list and return `true` if found and `false` if not found.

Hope this helps, didn't have the time to mock it up in a fiddle sorry.

[Edit] You find the value of the name input in the `$scope.investor.name` as far as I can figure, I never worked with x-editable.

Comment: Hi Paul, thx for ur input, I tried something here but it's still not working, maybe i'm missing something?    http://jsfiddle.net/Wbf8C/19/